# Powershell script to replace up to certain number of commas in each line

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that is comma-delimited, but the last field in each line is double-quoted and may contain commas within the quotes.  I need to have all the commas replaced with pipes `(like | )` EXCEPT for the ones within the quoted field at the end of each line.

Example of a line from the file:

```
2,1,24,Bourne,Jason,,06-01-1973,M,Ned,,Grove,,College Rd,72,1,01-10-2012,Null,85,S,"notes go here, and may contain commas."
```

I've run the following Powershell script but found that it replaces even the commas within the quotes at the end of the line:

```
(Get-Content c:\input.csv) 
    | % {$_ -replace ',', "|"} 
    | out-file -FilePath c:\output.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
```

I've been struggling for a couple hours now trying to come up with a regex to only replace the first 19 commas, but not much success so far.  My experience with regex is very limited so this is a learning experience for me.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what about grabbing everything on each line up until a `"` then running your replace on *that*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it through a RegEx to split it up for that last field, and do a replace on the first part like this:

```
GC C:\Input.csv |?{$_ -match "(.*?)(`"[^`"]*?`")"}|%{"$($Matches[1].replace(",","|"))$($Matches[2])"}| out-file -FilePath c:\output.csv -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: Had to choose this as the correct answer to the problem, as it was the one-liner that did the trick with no modifications.

Answer (score 2):

I would say don't bother with a regex and just use powershell's importing/exporting of csv features. The `export-csv` command lets you choose the delimeter:

```
import-csv C:\Input.csv | export-csv -Delimiter "|" -path c:\updated.csv
```

Comment: This method adds quotes to every field in the file.  This would require another operation to remove quotes from all fields except for the last field somehow.

Comment: @user3645507 Yup, it will. Note that with the quotes, it's still a valid csv file. But if that's a problem for you, then this probably isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to split at the ,"  and then do the replace in the first element, then rejoin with |"

```
$text = 
'2,1,24,Bourne,Jason,,06-01-1973,M,Ned,,Grove,,College Rd,72,1,01-10-2012,Null,85,S,"notes go here, and may contain commas."'

($text -split ',"')[0].Replace(',','|'),($text -split ',"')[1] -join '|"' 

2|1|24|Bourne|Jason||06-01-1973|M|Ned||Grove||College Rd|72|1|01-10-2012|Null|85|S|"notes go here, and may contain commas."
```

Or just split it at the quotes, and re-assemble with a format string:

```
'{0}"{1}"' -f $text.split('"')[0].replace(',','|'),$text.split('"')[1] 

2|1|24|Bourne|Jason||06-01-1973|M|Ned||Grove||College Rd|72|1|01-10-2012|Null|85|S|"notes go here, and may contain commas."
```